# Trying to Redirect Old Page to a New Page

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301, redirect

I've done searches and I've followed what they said but my redirect still isn't working.

.htaccess looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Redirect 301 /alaska http://www.example.com/alaska-schools?
Redirect 301 ^/delaware http://www.example.com/delaware-schools?
```

Any ideas what's not working here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to stick with mod_rewrite instead of mod_alias for these redirects. Having both directives (and one of them routing everything to `index.php`) will have them conflict. You will also want **all of your redirecting *before* your routing**. So something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^alaska/?$ http://www.example.com/alaska-schools? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^delaware/?$ http://www.example.com/delware-schools? [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```